# Looping through table to get single intersection from N>2 geometries using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, intersection

It's really clear how to apply ST_Intersection when you have only two geometries. But I am struggling with the situation where you have N>2 shapes and you want to compute a single one that represents intersection of all of them as a single geometry.

With the help of [ST_Intersection: Intersection of all geometries in a table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271824/st-intersection-intersection-of-all-geometries-in-a-table) I can get intersections for all pairs of geometries in a single table. But it is not exactly what I am trying to achieve though.

Let me try to illustrate the problem. What I have is this (simplified to only three geometries):

[image]

But what I am after is this:

[image]

I have over 5000 shapes in the table, so obviously I can't specify them explicitly.

I imagine a loop could be a solution, something like:

```
result = union(geometries) 
for geom in geometries:
    result = intersection(result, geom)
```

How would you achieve this with PostgreSQL/PostGIS?

Comment: do all of your geometries in one table and in one field? and do you want to get just one geometry (the result of the intersection of all of them)?

Comment: Records are in one table, one polygon per field (there are multiple polygons actually, but they don't overlap). I want only one resulting geometry, yes.

Comment: so all of your polygons in one (column)?. and you would like as your drawing shows to get just one polygon (intersection result of the of all of the intersected polygons). Sorry I repeat my question just to understand totally

Comment: yes, that's exactly right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a great application for a user-defined aggregate function, and I'm a bit wondering why this particular aggregate doesn't already exist in PostGIS. At its core, an aggregate function needs to do nothing more than iterate over a set of rows, maintaining a state (of type `stype`), and repeatedly calling a function (`sfunc`) that transforms a state and a row into a new state.

If this sounds like the `reduce` operator in languages like JavaScript, you're right - it's the exact same thing.

Aggregates can be complex to define (see [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html)), and it doesn't help that there are multiple versions of the syntax. But this is a pretty simple case:

```
CREATE AGGREGATE full_intersection (
  basetype = geometry,
  stype = geometry,
  sfunc = ST_Intersection
);
```

Here's an example of this aggregate in action, producing the inside of a Venn diagram:

```
CREATE table test (geom geometry);
INSERT INTO test SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(0,0), 0.75);
INSERT INTO test SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(1,0), 0.75);
INSERT INTO test SELECT ST_Buffer(ST_MakePoint(0.5,1), 0.75);

SELECT full_intersection(geom) FROM test;
```

Comment: It doesn't exist because this would be *very* inefficient for a large number of geometries, except in the case that few intersect and you rapidly end up with the empty geometry.

Comment: @jpmc26, what would be a good practice for the case you describe? Initial reduction of the set?

Comment: @mikitk I was working on an alternative answer, but I wasn't able to finish it yet. I'll post it later.

Comment: Good explanation of aggregates.  I don't think it would be hugely inefficient, if you first fed it the dumped result of ST_Union.

Comment: surprised this is the first time this question has been asked. Nice answer!

Comment: While this is definitely working solution, I am getting unexpected results. In my case the aggregate function returns empty `GeometryCollection`. In case anyone has a chance to have a look at the data I uploaded it:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/odgitsbqtxvimfg/sample.zip?dl=1. The geometry format is EWKB, but I don't think it should be a problem, or could it?

Comment: @miktik Not all of your geometries intersect, so the cumulative intersection is empty. If you want a cumulative intersection per group of intersecting geometries, you can group them first with `ST_ClusterDBSCAN`.

Comment: @dbaston is there no constraint to prohibit *stype* becoming empty/NULL during iteration? a fallback check would be nice...one could possibly implement a custom function/wrapper for ST_Intersection, but that seems somewhat clumsy...+1 anyways

Comment: For newer versions of postgis, I had to wrap the builtin `st_intersection` into a separate function because of the new `gridSize` parameter.  So I replaced the `sfunc` parameter with the wrapped function.

Comment: on postgres 14.7 & postgis 3.2.4 i get the following error on running the "CREATE AGGREGATE"-statement:  "SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: function st_intersection(geometry, geometry) does not exist" is that error related to camdenl's comment ? and if, how do I have to change the initial statement from dbaston ?

Answer (score 5):

The aggregate function answer is perhaps the most elegant way to do this.  But another option is to use a recursive CTE.  This may provide more flexibility in some situations. It's also a nice use of the standard recursive CTE "running total" pattern.

[image: Example data with total intersection]

Here's a solution, with some example data:

```
WITH RECURSIVE 
data(geom) AS (VALUES
('POLYGON ((50 150, 100 200, 250 50, 200 0, 50 150))'),
('POLYGON ((200 200, 250 150, 100 0, 50 50, 200 200))'),
('POLYGON ((120 200, 180 200, 180 0, 120 0, 120 200))'),
('POLYGON ((50 130, 50 70, 250 70, 250 130, 50 130))')
),
seq AS 
(
  SELECT geom::geometry, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS i
    FROM data
),
intgeoms AS (
    SELECT i, geom, geom AS intgeom
      FROM seq
      WHERE i = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT seq.i, seq.geom, ST_Intersection(intgeom, seq.geom) AS intgeom
      FROM intgeoms INNER JOIN seq
        ON seq.i = intgeoms.i + 1
)
SELECT i, intgeom
  FROM intgeoms
  ORDER BY i DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The way it works is:

- the `seq` query computes a sequential index for each geometry in the set to be intersected
- the `intgeoms` query interates over each geometry in the sequence, keeping a "running total" of the intersections

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following using a loop by converting your geom to an array:

```
create or replace function ST_IntersectionArray(geom geometry[]) returns geometry as $$
declare
   i integer;
   tmpGeom geometry;
begin
    tmpGeom := geom[1];
    FOR i IN 1..array_length(geom,1) LOOP
      tmpGeom:= ST_Intersection(tmpGeom,geom[i]);
    END LOOP;
    return tmpGeom;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And the result (table=your table name)

```
SELECT ST_IntersectionArray(ARRAY(select geom from table));
```

to check! insert your result in a new table (result)

```
Create table result as 
SELECT ST_IntersectionArray(ARRAY(select geom from table)); 

  select * from table result
```

Tested (the result in QGIS) working.

[Reference (ST_Intersection of multiple polygons in one table)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60281/query-to-find-the-intersection-coordinates-of-multiple-polyon/60295#60295)

PS: I tried the answer using aggregate, it gives me the same with my answer, actually perfect to use aggregate. but sometimes using arrays has an advantage if someone wants to work on a just specific number of polygons

Comment: is there anyway you can explain the code from the begin to end statement.

Comment: tmpGeom := geom[1]; why geom[1]? shouldnt it just be an empty array?

Comment: FOR i IN 1..array_length(geom,1) LOOP 1..array_length(geom,1) LOOP don't understand this syntax

Comment: defining geom[1] to access just one geom each time in the loop iteration. The second line is to loop over all geom and add one geom as row in the array

Comment: @ziggy that's assigning the first array element to *tmpGeom*, you just need one to start with for `ST_Intersection` - in the loop, assign the result of `ST_Intersection` between the initial geom and the next to *tmpGeom* - repeat. you could start with 2 in the `FOR` loop here btw.

Comment: @ThingimaBob Yeah exactly, I started with 2 and it works, thanks for the clarification